# Can't access a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, debugging, dom

I am simply trying to append a string to an existing DOM element using jQuery.  I've done this 1,000 times before but for some reason my code is misbehaving.  The following example works perfectly as one would expect:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

<ul id="myList">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <li>third list item</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
        //alert('Here I am');
    });
</script>
```

Now in my application, I am dynamically rendering the unordered list and associated li's which, again, has never been a problem before.  I can't seem to figure out why my click function isn't appending to the myList object.  I've even tried straight from FireBug console the following:

```
>>$('#myList').hide()
```

and again nothing happens.  I confirmed that the DOM element id "myList" exists, I just can't manipulate or interact with it.  What's the best way to debug something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean `ul` in your unordered list?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is running on your page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xBPr5/ - it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you're dynamically generating the `ul` then you will want to use [`jQuery live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):</strike>

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

<lu id="myList">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <li>third list item</li>
</lu>

<script>
    $('#submit').live('click',function(){
        $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
        //alert('Here I am');
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Alas, `live()` does not appear to make a difference: http://jsfiddle.net/citizenconn/YBZSJ/

Perhaps try in firebug:

```
alert($);
```

Just to make sure you're calling it properly. Notice in my fiddle, if you call `$('#myList').hide();` nothing happens, but if you call `hide()` on the element itself it works.

Im leaving this answer here for reference.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference because the click event is attached to the input, not the list.

Comment: +1 props to you for catching that line where he's dynamically adding the unordered list.

Comment: : ) thx. I think the live does apply here because the contents of the live function also matter, not just the element that the event is attached to. This is worth a test though.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `<ul>` as others have said. `<lu>` is not an HTML tag.

Your problem is likely caused by creating multiple lists with the same `Id` as an existing element on the page. The `Id` must be unique for this to work too, because jQuery will probably just select one element if you select by Id. Not to mention your code is invalid and both CSS and DOM manipulations could have unexpected results. If you have more than one of these lists on the page at once you should make it a class instead of an id, or if they all have the same parent, give that parent an idea and use it to select the `<ul>`s

Comment: I had a typo on my original post (lu instead of ul) and I confirmed that there is only one list on the page and therefore one ID.  I also tried both the live and delegate approaches suggested above with the same effect.

Comment: Here's another avenue I am investigating...this <ul> is wrapped in a <div> which gets toggled to show/hide. I changed this div so that it is always display: block and never hidden.

If I can't get to the object in FireBug console, do you have any suggestions as to how to debug?

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are correct that you need a future-proof event observer since you are dynamically creating the elements and the binds need to be attached after they are created. That being said, `live()` is extremely expensive. Delegate is up to 3x faster than `live()`:

Try this:

```
$(document.body).delegate('#submit','click',function(){
    $('#myList').hide();
});
```

Benchmarking evidence: http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-jquery-delegate/15

Comment: +1 for that tip. However, check out my fiddle where live() doesn't actually make a difference.

Comment: interesting, my append calls weren't working but it seems to be working for you. nice.

Comment: You were appending to `$('ul')` instead of `$('#base')`. Not sure off hand why JQ didn't like that :/

Answer (score 0):

[Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/4m325/).

Also, you've got `<lu>` where you mean `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `lu` instead of `ul`

```
<lu id="myList">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <li>third list item</li>
</lu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (.live() instead of .click()):

```
$('#submit').live('click', function(){
    $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
    //alert('Here I am');
});
```